# Typecasting by bit copy

Tags: c

I want to typecast a `float` as an `int`. However, this does not do a bit by bit copy. Is it possible to typecast a `float` into an `int` while maintaining all the bits (sign, exponent, mantissa)?

Comment: This can only work if `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(int)`. I don't feel like googling for the answer if this is guaranteed by the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most languages allow something like that, in C it is like:

```
float f = 3.14f;
int i = *(int*)&f;
```

Comment: Although this may very well work in most cases, it triggers a warning in GCC because it violates strict-aliasing - which is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: That's interesting - it didn't raise a warning in my GCC (4.4.3)?

Comment: @Ozbekov: It will if you enabled strict-aliasing (IIRC `--fstrict-aliasing`)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do this in a completely C-compliant way, but you could use unions:

```
union{
    int i;
    float f;
} u;

u.f = 123.456;  //  Your value.

//  Read u.i.
```

This should still work on nearly all systems today. And of course assumes that `float` and `int` are the same size.

The alternative is to use pointer casting, but strictly speaking, that violates strict-aliasing and is considered undefined behavior.

---

Another (possibly compliant - see comments) approach is to use `memcpy()`:

```
int i;
float f;

f = 123.456;  //  Your value.

memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof(int));

//  Read i
```

Comment: I believe this is unspecified behaviour (which you mention in your first sentence, albeit obtusely). Appendix J1 of C99 states "The following are unspecified: ... the value of a union member other than the last one stored into". Unspecfied sits between implementation-defined and undefined behaviour - the implementation does not have to document how a choice is made as to what the results are. Still, there's no other (all-C)-safe way to do it so +1.

Comment: But as far as I know gcc guarantees that type punning via unions works with it, so if it needn't be portable, it's fine.

Comment: @trinithis I was thinking about that too... and was debating whether or not that would violate strict-aliasing. EDIT: I'll add this into any answer as well since it's definitely worth consideration.

Comment: Also, could you get around strict aliasing via using `char*` indirection multiple times? If it isn't undefined, it might be unspecified. Remember char star can alias anything.

Comment: That definitely seems possible. Though it's starting to get messy at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29#C.2FC.2B.2B).

```
union
{
    int tmp;
    float f;
} u;

u.f = z;
```

Then `u.tmp` is the same bits. (Code taken from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Approximations_that_depend_on_IEEE_representation)).